# Integral $\int_1^\infty \mathrm{d}z\: z^2 K_\nu (a z)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a general expression for the solution to the integral

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty \mathrm{d} z \: z^2 K_\nu(a z)\,,
\end{equation}

where $K_\nu(z)$ is the modified Besself function of the second kind, $\nu$ is a positive integer and $a$ is a positive real number?

I wonder if there is a solution in terms of equivalent or more general special functions, e.g. for $\nu=1$ we have
\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty \mathrm{d} z \: z^2 K_1(a z) = \frac{K_2(a)}{a}\,.
\end{equation}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes, https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use the result on NIST, however that is specifically for (indefinite) integrals of the form
\begin{equation}
\int \mathrm{d} z \: z^{\nu +1} K_\nu (z)\,,
\end{equation}
while here I need a result when the variable $z$ inside the integral is always only to the power of 2, e.g.
\begin{equation}
\int \mathrm{d} z \: z^2 K_2(z) = \: ??? \,.
\end{equation}
I think Mathematica can find a result to the former integral in terms of the Meijer G-function, but this is rather impractical as the numerical integration is then just faster.